# Microsoft ODBC for Oracle and JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, odbc, driver

Is the Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle compatible with JDBC? If so, could an example be given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java ships with a JDBC-ODBC bridge, so if you can make a connection with ODBC, you can use the JDBC-ODBC bridge. However, the Oracle JDBC driver is to be preferred, since this is software provided by Oracle for connecting to their database. There is a driver for each database server version. The [Oracle JDBC driver is a free download](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html) (after you create an account)

Comment: Readers should also bear in mind that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge is obsolete and has been removed from Java 8.